# Having Issue with WYSIWYG editor

Tags: php, html, ckeditor

Hi I am having issue saving the edited page.

The WYSIWYG editor is called CkEditor.

This is my Admin

```
<?php
session_start();
header("Cache-control: private");
require_once ('../include/back.php');
include_once("../ckeditor/ckeditor.php");?>
<html>
<head>
<title>ADMIN</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<br>
<form action="../article.php" method="post" target="_blank">
<?php
$CKEditor->basePath = '/ckeditor/';
$CKEditor = new CKEditor();
$CKEditor->editor("editor1", $initialValue);
$initialValue = '<p>Words</p>';
?>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the second page which is my article page:

```
<?php
session_start();
header("Cache-control: private");
include("include/back.php");
?>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div align="center">
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<?php
$editor_data = $_POST[ 'editor1' ];
echo $editor_data;
?>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I can't save my article page file (html) from CKeditor. The CKeditor works when I type something and published it but when I click on the menu link to the same page and it's blank.

Any suggestion or explanation would be appreciated. Any examples will also helpful too. T

Comment: To make things clear, you are putting the content into editor and then clicking on the menu instead of submit button? In that case you are not sending form so nothing will be saved. You either need to submit form or bind event to menu link so when clicked it would send the form (but I don't think that this is good solution)

Comment: Hi Nick,Thanks for the reply. I put the content into the editor then click submit and it publish the page but when I click on the menu to see if it was save but it went blank.

Comment: What do you mean bind the event to the menu link, that's something very interested. How do you do that?

Comment: Why are you setting `$initialValue` after you use it?

Comment: Hi luxun, Thanks for the reply. I follow the instructions from the website and from the download zip file. Did I installed it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your article page uses only the following code to display what you have entered to the editor?

```
<?php
    $editor_data = $_POST[ 'editor1' ];
    echo $editor_data;
?>
```

`$_POST` variable is populated with every request. It is not meant to store data for more than 1 request. You must take this data and save it in more persistent form like writing to database or to a file. With this code you can see what you have entered to the editor but only when you send it. The text will be lost once the page is generated and sent to your browser. Any other user won't see that simply because he didn't send this data. You also won't see it when you return to the page.

Comment: Hi Zefiryn,Thanks for the reply. Yes, If I can't used $POST then what variable do I used? How do I take this data and save it into the database. Do you have an example for me to see how it works. I want to learn it and just need to know how it function. Will it be in php? or mysql? because you mention database. You're right about the "Any other user won't see that simply because he didn't send this data. You also won't see it when you return to the page." What Do I do now?

Comment: It seems you're starting to know php and the question of processing forms is more complicated than few sentence answer. I suggest you to look for some php tutorials for beginners (https://www.google.pl/search?sourceid=chrome&client=ubuntu&channel=cs&ie=UTF-8&q=php+%2B+mysql+tutorial) or buy yourself a book. When I was starting with php I used this one: http://www.amazon.com/PHP5-MySQL-Bible-Tim-Converse/dp/0764557467
You probably find something suitable when you check your local bookstore.

Comment: Hi Zefiryn, thanks for mentioning the books but I doubt they have the example of creating the database from CKeditor. This is something not from the book. I have some books but none of it actually mention about merge editors with database.

Comment: CKeditor has nothing to do with this. It is just user interface, underneath are just data which must be processed as any kind of form data. Learn how to do that and you will know how to save text from rich text editor.

Comment: You sound very upset. I just want to learn. You mean like this (this is the first time I'm on stackoverflow, I"m not familiar with the posting)                          $page = $_GET['page'];
$sqlcats="SELECT * FROM pages WHERE pagename = '".$page."'";
//echo $sqlcats;
$rscats= mysql_query($sqlcats) ;
while($rowcats = mysql_fetch_array($rscats))
{
$thetext = $rowcats["editor1"];
$pagename = $rowcats["pagename"];
}

Comment: I am not upset at all, I just want to point out that your case is not something non-typical. The above code retrieves data from database but I cannot comment on that (except that you are not escaping `$page` variable) since I don't know the table structure.

Comment: Thanks, actually my $page is article.php like what you mention I need to retrieve the data from the database. I used mysql_fetch_array and end up with mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean. Hi Zefiryn how do I post these sricpts correctly, I can't seem find it, I don't want to post this here. Kinda want it to be like yours.

Comment: You need to connect to the database with `mysql_connect()` and select databse with `mysql_select_db()` first.

Comment: I did step it up (my database), it's connected. OK, now I realize I think I get, you mean I have to create a mysql_connect() & mysql_select_db() function. In order to resolve mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean?

Comment: mysql_fetch_array expects to receive argument that is a valid mysql resource handler so it can retrieve data from it. As your code looks ok I suspect that you didn't connect or select database.

Comment: OK, I understand now, thanks for being patience, sorry for the confusing. I will work on it tonight and post my results tomorrow. I appreciated you taking your time to help me.

Comment: I double check my mysql_connect() & mysql_select_db() and I'm still getting the error

Comment: Are you sure you have a table named pages with column pagename?

Comment: Hi Zefiryn, Sorry for replying back late. Yes Zefiryn, I do have a table called pages. I think it might be my spelling. I will double my spellings on the pages if it's matches up. Thanks. I will get back to you!

Comment: Hi Zefiryn, It work! I guess I was careless not double checking my database with my script. But I solve, thanks for help! I apprecaite your help very much!